# Error when sideloading an Outlook add-in

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

When I try to sideload my Outlook add-in, created based on the last Ignite session by Andrew Salamatov, I get following error when I add the add-in from a URL (https://bulkpermissiondemo.azurewebsites.net/manifest-bulkpermission.xml): **"The app can't be installed. This app isn't supported by the version of Exchange Server that your account connects to."**

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks :-)

Comment: What version of Exchange are you trying to install this to?

Comment: 15.1.707.9 - thanks @Jason-Johnston

Comment: Is this your own server or an Office 365 server?

Comment: This is a Office 365 server

Comment: We’ve tried installing the manifest provided in the link but were unable to reproduce the error listed in the original post on recent builds. Could you try installing the manifest again and see if the same error occurs? If so, would you be willing to provide the email address for the account you are trying to install the add-in to?  Then we can take a look at the server logs to see what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

We’ve tried installing the manifest provided in the link but were unable to reproduce the error listed in the original post on recent builds. Could you try installing the manifest again and see if the same error occurs? If so, would you be willing to provide the email address for the account you are trying to install the add-in to? Then we can take a look at the server logs to see what the issue might be.